# Configuracion de webpack.config.js

Tags: javascript, webpack

Hola que tal tengo el siguiente archivo webpack.config.js el cual quisiera ejecutarlo en modo produccion desde mi consola.

```
const webpack = require('webpack')

const CaseSensitivePathsPlugin = require('case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin');
const path = require('path')

const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin')
const extractSCSS = new ExtractTextPlugin('stylesheets/[name].css')
    //const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin')

const devBuild = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
const nodeEnv = devBuild ? 'development' : 'production'

const config = {
    entry: {
        // Add polyfills
        'client-bundle': ['babel-polyfill', 'whatwg-fetch', './client/js/clientEntryPoint.js'],
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'web/assets/build/'),
        publicPath: '/assets/build/',
        filename: '[name].js',
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
    },
    plugins: [
        new CaseSensitivePathsPlugin(),
        extractSCSS,
        // Provide jQuery and lodash to every module (remove if you don't need these)
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            _: 'lodash',
            $: 'jquery',
            'jQuery': 'jquery',
            'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
        }),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env': {
                NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify(nodeEnv),
            },
        }),
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            // Expose webpacks jQuery to the browser so we can reuse this instance e.g. to chain loaded plugins
            { test: require.resolve('jquery'), loader: 'expose-loader?$!expose-loader?jQuery' },
            { test: /\.jsx?$/, loader: 'babel-loader', exclude: /node_modules/ },
            { test: /\.scss$/i, loader: extractSCSS.extract(['css-loader', 'sass-loader']) },
            {
                test: /\.(woff|woff2)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
                loader: 'url-loader',
                options: { limit: 10000, mimetype: 'application/font-woff' }
            },
            {
                test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
                loader: 'url-loader',
                options: { limit: 10000, mimetype: 'application/octet-stream' }
            },
            { test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'file-loader' },
            {
                test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
                loader: 'url-loader',
                options: { limit: 10000, mimetype: 'image/svg+xml' }
            },
            { test: /\.jpe?g$/, loader: 'file-loader' }
        ],
    }
}

if (devBuild) {
    console.log('Webpack compilando en modo desarrollo')
    config.devtool = '#eval-source-map'
} else {
    config.plugins.push(
        new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin()
    )
    console.log('Webpack compilando en modo produccion')
}

module.exports = config
```

Lo ejecuto con el siguiente comando `webpack --config webpack.config.js --define process.env.NODE_ENV='production'` pero no me cambia a modo producción. Gracias por leer esta duda

Comment: intenta de esta forma `webpack export NODE_ENV=production --config webpack.config.js`

Comment: Nada de esa forma tampoco funciona me sigue devolviendo la variable devBuild= true lo que me indica que se  esta ejecutando en modo desarrollo; lo que no entiendo es porque si en la ayuda dice que con --define se cambia el valor de una variable no me funciona..

Comment: es que te devuelve true por que no estas recibiendo algun parametro

Comment: si estas en lo cierto porque la mando a imprimir por consola y me devuelve `undefined`

Comment: te falta agregar un paquete, estoy buscando una forma para que no ageges paquetes y sea mas facil

Comment: muchas gracias por continuar alludandome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esto es redundante:

```
var nodeEnv = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
const nodeEnv = devBuild ? 'development' : 'production'
```

Solo de basta:

```
const ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'production'.
```

Lo anterior dice:

> Si no existe la variable de entorno `NODE_ENV`, retorna `production`.

Finalmente debes establecer la variable de entorno en tu sesión de terminal.

**Bash**

```
export NODE_ENV=development
```

**CMD**

```
set NODE_ENV=development
```

**Powershell**

```
$env:NODE_ENV="development"
```

Es preferible que ante la falta de la variable de entorno, se considere como producción; de lo contrario, cuando despliegues la aplicación tendrás que crear un script bash para primero establecer la variable de entorno y luego ejecutar la aplicación.

Comment: Muchas gracias me sirvió correctamente

Answer (score 0):

En tu Packaje.json agrega la siguiente linea:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack --config webpack.config.js ",
    "test": "webpack --config webpack.config_2.js  ",

  }
```

en consola ejecutas `npm start` o `npm test` y **puedes definir que configuracion ejecutar**

Comment: no ninguno de los dos cambia a modo produccion ademas en el "pruebas" me da error porque creo que hay que ponerlo asi `webpack export NODE_ENV=dev --config webpack.config.js` pero igual cuando lo arreglo no me funciona tampoco

Comment: que error te da?

Comment: esta opcion te gustaria?

Comment: bueno esa que editasete ahora no da error pero en la anterior parece que se te fue y pusiste el expor antes de webpack, pero esa que editaste, no me cambia a modo produccion, yo estuve investigando -p que es un comando para produccion tampoco me cambia a entorno de produccion

Comment: leistes algo en internet y te falto te puedo traducir la respuesta pero obviamente no se si funcionara, lo que si te puedo comentar es que en el script dentro del package.json define los comandos a ejecutar alli puedes hacer npm start o npm test; y desde el package.json puedes decir que configuracion buscar

Comment: si con eso estoy de acuerdo, lo que te decia era que la configuración anterior me daba un error, pero despues lo arrgle y no me soluciono nada

Comment: a pocierto en el otro comentario dime si tienes conocimiento de trabajar con axios y symfony

Comment: en la respuesta que te di de esa forma lo trabajo yo

Comment: entonces tienes dos archivo webpack uno para la producción y otro para el desarrollo, yo vi un ejemplo que usa material-ui con webpack que uza dos archivos uno para desarrollo y otro para produccion, pero estoy seguro que debe de haber alguna forma de usarlo asi.. Mira este es el proyecto con el que estoy trabajano ahi esta la configuracion de webpack y del package.json  ** https://github.com/Limenius/symfony-react-sandbox.git**

Comment: alli lo tiene npm run webpack-dev,  es la respuesta que te di!

Comment: no entiendo tu ultimo comentario

Comment: lo que te explique del script ellos ya lo tienen implementado observa el package.json y tienen dos lineas npm run webpack-dev y el npm run  webpack-serverside en este caso la usan para distintas cosas; pero puedes agregar el modo dev y el modo prod

Comment: si en eso estoy de acuerdo contigo pero el problema es como cambiarlo por consola, pues uno es para renderizar desde el servidor y otro para el cliente yo se que eso no influye en nada pero el problema es cambiar el modo por la consola

Comment: aprende nano es mas facil

Comment: no entiendo lo que dices